# Why doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events

Why it doesn't work? I want that both the number and the "h3" on scroll receive a x transform of the amount of data

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  var target = document.querySelectorAll('.speg');
  var offset = window.pageYOffset;
  var index = 0,
    length = target.length;

  for (index; index < length; index++) {

    var pos = offset * target[index].dataset.xoff;
    target[index].style.transform = 'translateX(0px' + pos + ')'

  }

})
```

```html
<div class="spiegazione">
  <div class="speg-sub">
    <img class="speg" data-xoff='5' src="./svg/number1.svg">
    <h3 class="speg">TITLE</h3>
    <p class="text-spiegazione">Lorem ipsum </p>
    <img class="speg" data-xoff='5' src="./svg/number2.svg">
    <h3 class="speg">TITLE</h3>
    <p class="text-spiegazione"> Lorem ipsum </p>
    <img class="speg" data-xoff='5' src="./svg/number3.svg">
    <h3 class="speg">TITLE</h3>
    <p class="text-spiegazione"> Lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code you have "0px" and then "pos". Remove the zero and add "px" *after* "pos" instead. This will cause all '.spegs's to move right as you scroll (just checked it).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a date tag for one element and there are still some problems, see my example

https://jsfiddle.net/4w58ed3o/2/

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  var target = document.querySelectorAll('.speg');
  var offset = window.pageYOffset;
  var index = 0,
    length = target.length;
  for (index; index < length; index++) {

    var pos = offset * target[index].dataset.xoff || 0;
    console.log('translateX(' + pos + 'px)');
    target[index].style.transform = 'translateX(' + pos + 'px)'

  }
})
```